# Chromecast Network I/O Error

Tags: ios, google-cast

When trying to substitute my App ID for "TicTacToe" in the example from gethub I get the error:

> castApplicationSessionDidFailToStartWithError: failed to start application (com.google.GCKFramework.GCKApplicationSessionError); caused by: network I/O error (com.google.GCKFramework.GCKNetworkRequestError)

I have whitelisted my device and checked the box in settings to send the serial number to Google.

Im not sure how much difference it makes but my App ID is formatted like a URL. 
For example:

> "http://example.co/Chromecast/test.html"

Thank you for the help.

Edit:

This is the line of code I altered in an attempt to cast.

Im not sure what goes here. I have tried both the http and the Hex ID

> static NSString * const kReceiverApplicationName = @"TicTacToe";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The App ID should be a string with hex characters like:
xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx

Contact Google using the email address provided to you when you got the whitelisted information.

Comment: When I use my Hex ID I get "entity not found error". Im not sure if this is a step forward or back. I will try to point out the code I changed above

Comment: You are right. I had restored it to factory settings and went to check the box it was not checked. The Hex ID worked in place of the "TicTacToe" Thanks!!